# Color coding certain regex match in a textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea

Is there any way via JS to highlight text inside a textarea that matches a specific pattern?

I am loathe to use a fully WYSIWYG editor as I just want to highlight certain text (references in scientific writeups, they become very cumbersome to read over).

Comment: Don't think one can do that, can't have html inside a textarea. The best way is probably to replace the textarea with an `iframe` which can have html in it. I suppose you'll have to use JS to catch the key presses and enter the content as well though.

Comment: the question was solved in another post:

[Solved here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/142527/highlight-text-inside-of-a-textarea

Answer (score 1):

textarea can not support different colors. So your answer is you can not do it in a textarea.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this article: [Javascript - Change font color of certain text in textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102149/javascript-change-font-color-of-certain-text-in-textarea)

Summarized, you cannot add tags inside of a textarea, so you cannot modify the font/style of text contained within it.