# Styling certain text in textarea

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to only style certain text in a `<textarea>` element? I'm aware that you can't insert any other HTML tags within a `<textarea>` and would prefer not to resort to something hacky like creating a ghost or overlay element.

Use case: highlight any links inserted into the `<textarea>` with some font styles. It doesn't appear that the `contentEditable` really supports that, per this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/1102242/849761 but as you can probably tell, I'm not a UI developer

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible to style certain parts of text in a `textarea` element. You have to use [contentEditable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Rich-Text_Editing_in_Mozilla). The answer you've cited is from 2009 - contentEditable is supported by all major browsers now.

You'll need to write the logic to determine when a link has been entered or provide a way in the UI to add a link and use `execCommand`. But otherwise, the CSS is as simple as:

```
div[contenteditable="true"] a {
  /* styles */
}
```

Comment: How does this work? Your CSS reference looks like its simply an ``<a>`` tag associated to the element. Does that mean any (and all) ``<a...>`` tags in the ``contentEditable`` section will automatically have the style applied, with the exception that they need to be defined in HTML form?

Comment: All `<a>` tags within the contentEditable `<div>` will get these styles. There's nothing special about this CSS selector, it's very basic.